# TemplateDoesNotExist at certain location

Tags: python, django

My code was working perfectly fine until yesterday. I had deployed the app on Heroku and it went well. I wanted to work on the security of the app, so today I deployed some code changes directly to Heroku. When it didn't run perfectly, I reverted the changes and by mistake, I copied the settings.py from my production server to development server. Now the deployed code is running perfectly, though my development server is unable to find the templates!

When I realized that I'm using the production settings.py, I made the necessary changes. `Debug = True`, removed security headers and made sure the middlewares were the default ones.

Initially, I kept getting the below error while accessing https://localhost:8000

```
You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

I then changed my URL to simply 127.0.0.1:8000, and then I started getting the below error

```
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: my_form/index.html
[11/Jun/2019 23:25:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 88781
```

I've even tried to start the project from scratch and even cleared my cache from the browser.

Project Structure:

```
├───my_server
│   ├───my_form
│   │   ├───migrations
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───static
│   │   │   └───raffle_form
│   │   │       ├───images
│   │   │       └───styles
│   │   ├───templates
│   │   │   └───my_form
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───my_server
│       └───__pycache__
```

Here is the urls.py from my_server:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('my_form.urls')),
]
```

Here is the urls.py from my_form:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Here is the views.py from my_form app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'my_form/index.html')
```

I've created a templates folder within `my_form` app. Within templates, I've `my_form` folder which contains the `index.html` files

I'm pretty sure nothing is wrong with the setup since it was already working. I believe the trick would be either to flush some files or update something in my `settings.py`

I would have shared my `settings.py` if there was something to show, but its just the default one.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost a two day bout with the problem, I decided to go back even further, and reinstall Django packages. For some unknown reason, it solved my issue. However, I'm still not sure if any package/module/definition was missing, why it wasn't reported in the logs?!

To anyone struggling with the same issue, I would suggest going back one step at a time.

- Check your app's `views.py` and `urls.py`.
- Check your projects `urls.py`.
- Check if you've registered the app in the `settings.py`.
- Check `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\django\template` directory for relevant files`

As for other experts, who might have some light to throw in here, please feel free to comment/post.

Answer (score 0):

If someone ever experience this again, please take a look at `settings.py` and ensure the `INSTALLED_APPS` contains the app you want to render the template.

[image: settings.py]